# Plotting a complex function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a complex function to plot using Python, and then I have to find its root using ridder's method.

This is what I've done so far with my code but I keep running into a syntax error on a simple part of my code and have tried loads of things but nothing has given me a different result.

```
import math as m 
from math import log
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
t = arange(0,250,0.1)
M = 2.8*10**6
n = 13.3*10**3
g = 9.8
u = 2510
plt.plot(u*(np.log((M)/(M-(n*t)))-g*t, t, 'r-^')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('velocity')
plt.show
```

Im being told my line where I am doing plt.xlabel has a syntax error and I can only assume the next line will do the same and I am not sure why.
Can someone point out my mistake please ?

Comment: You are missing a trailing parenthesis: plt.plot(u*(np.log((M)/(M-(n*t)))-g*t, t, 'r-^'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first** of all, arange belongs to numpy so you have to use np.arange
**second**, check parenthesis!

```
import math as m 
from math import log
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
t = np.arange(0,250,0.1) #first line changed
M = 2.8*10**6
n = 13.3*10**3
g = 9.8
u = 2510
plt.plot(u*(np.log((M)/(M-(n*t))))-g*t, t, 'r-^') #second line changed
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('velocity')
plt.show
```

here what I got!:
[image: matplotlib of your function]